# How does reassigning the timeout variable impact Settimeout

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Consider This:

```js
var x = null;

function a() {
  x = window.setTimeout(() => {
    alert("hello")
  })
}

a();

function b() {
  window.clearTimeout(x);
  alert("bye")
}

b();
```

The above snippet would only print `bye` and not `hello`. However, if I just reassign x in the method `b`, both `hello` and `bye` would be printed. What's the mechanism?

```js
var x = null;

function a() {
  x = window.setTimeout(() => {
    alert("hello")
  })
}

a();

function b() {
  x = undefined;
  window.clearTimeout(x);
  alert("bye")
}

b();
```

Comment: Nothing special at all. You set the timer, store the reference in `x`, and then discard the reference when you do `x = undefined`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "timeout variable" is just a number, the ID of the timeout. Reassigning the variable the number is assigned to isn't a problem in itself, but if you want to clear a timeout, you'll have to pass the same timeout ID to the `clearTimeout`. Just for illustration, not that you should do this in real code, you can call `setTimeout` at the beginning of pageload and get a timeout ID of 1, then call `clearTimeout` with `1`, and the timeout will be cleared:

```js
x = window.setTimeout(() => {
  alert("hello")
});
window.clearTimeout(1);
```

The variable itself is nothing special, it's just the *value*, the number, that you need to keep track of so you can pass it to `clearTimeout`.

In your second snippet, because you're assigning `undefined` to `x` before doing `clearTimeout(x)`, the interpreter doesn't know of an ongoing timeout with an id of `undefined`, so it doesn't clear anything.

You could also assign the timeout ID number to a *different* variable, and clear the original variable:

```js
var x = null;

function a() {

  x = window.setTimeout(() => {
    alert("hello")
  })
}
a();

function b() {
  const savedX = x;
  x = undefined;
  window.clearTimeout(savedX);
  alert("bye")
}
b();
```

Comment: But shouldn't  window.clearTimeout(x) be executed when the function b is executed which is after the function a is executed?

Comment: The functions are just a distraction from the meat of the problem - feel free to imagine the code without them. What matters is that `x = window.setTimeout` runs first, assigning the timeout ID to `x`. Then, later, `clearTimeout` needs to be called with the same value that was assigned to `x` for the timeout to be cleared.

Comment: I understood that part. What's confusing me is why it ran first. Why does window.clearTimeout execute before the function b runs?

Comment: Because `a()` comes before `b()` at the top level of the code, so `x = window.setTimeout` in `a` runs before `window.clearTimeout` in `b`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant why does `window.clearTimeout` execute before the function b runs? I wrote `window.setTimeout` instead. I edited my comment.
So why isn't "hello" alerted since `a` (where the timeout is set) runs before `b` (where the timeout is cleared).

Comment: `setTimeout` callbacks occur in a *macrotask*, which will run only after the current call stack is cleared. A script's synchronous code will run to the very end before any `setTimeout` callbacks have a chance of running.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yup, Got it. Thank you. As you said, variable isn't important here, it's the Value. That is ALSO the reason why the following would print both "bye" and "hello" as when the timeout is cleared, it's only "number" that's stored in X gets cleared:

var x = null;
function a(){
  
  x= window.setTimeout(()=>{
    alert("hello")
  })
}
a();

function c(){
  
  x= window.setTimeout(()=>{
    alert("hello 2")
  })
}
c();

function b(){
 window.clearTimeout(x);
  alert("bye")
  
}
b();

Answer (score 0):

It's because `window.clearTimeout(x);` invokes first and clear the timeouts that's why no `hello` alert.

If you use `setTimeout` without delay parameter it executes the next event cycle, which means after the `b()` execution in your case.

In second scenario you are reassigning the `x` to `undefined` so x no longer points to the same `setTiemout` `ID`. Hence `window.clearTimeout(x)` doesn't clear the timeout.

[From MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Syntax)

> delay
>
> The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should wait before the specified function or code is executed. If this argument is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, the next event cycle. Note that in either case, the actual delay may be longer than intended;